# Sort data in a list to columns for xlsx files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, openpyxl

I have a list that looks something like this. (The data is from several xlsx files):

```
[['A B 10', 2, 'A B 10', 3, 1, AC], ['A B 104', 3, 'A B 104', 2, -1, 'AC']]
[['D B 126', 3, 'D B 126', 2, -1, 'EFG 1'], ['D B 15', 3, 'D B 15', 2, -1, 'EFG 1']
[]
[]
[['D B 544', 2, 'D B 544', 1, -1, 'EFG 11'], ['D B 152', 3, 'D B 152', 2, -1, 'EFG 11'], ['D B 682', 3, 'D B 682', 2, -1, 'EFG 11']
```

I want to put this information into a new xlsx file, but first I need to sort the data into rows and columns. I want all of the first strings in each sub-lists to be added to the first column, the numbers in the second column etc. So the columns is to be where the comma signs are. I also do not want the list to have sub lists, so everything should be in the same list. Something like this:

```
['A B 10', 2, 'A B 10', 3, 1, AC, 
 'A B 104', 3, 'A B 104', 2, -1, 'AC'
 'D B 126', 3, 'D B 126', 2, -1, 'EFG 1'
 'D B 15', 3, 'D B 15', 2, -1, 'EFG 1'
 'D B 544', 2, 'D B 544', 1, -1, 'EFG 11'
 'D B 152', 3, 'D B 152', 2, -1, 'EFG 11' 
 'D B 682', 3, 'D B 682', 2, -1, 'EFG 11']
```

This is how far I have come on my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import glob
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

numbers = []
os.chdir(r'C:Myfolder')
files = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
print(files)
for file in files: #Getting the data from xlsx files and to the numbers-list
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    m = (df.iloc[:,4] - df.iloc[:,1]) != 0
    pos = [0,1,3,4,6,7]
    numbers = (df.loc[m, df.columns[pos]].values.tolist())
    print(numbers)
excel_input = load_workbook(rapp) #Going from using pandas and dataframes to working with openpyxl (Just because I am not that familiar with pandas).
ws = excel_input.active
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
else:
    pass

col1 = [] #Creating open lists to put the data into columns
col2 = []
col4 = []
col5 = []
col7 = []
col8 = []

mainlist = []
try:
    for row in numbers: #Putting the data into the columns lists
        col1.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value) #This is wrong, and is throwing the error
        col2.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value) #Wrong
        col4.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=4).value) #Wrong
        col5.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=5).value) #Wrong
        col7.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=7).value) #Wrong
        col8.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=8).value) #Wrong
except AttributeError:
    logging.error('Something is wrong')
finally:
    columns = zip(col1, col2, col4, col5, col7, col8) #Zipping the lists
    for column in columns:
        mainlist.append(column)
```

> Traceback: 
>           col1.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value)
>       File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line
>   306, in cell
>           if row < 1 or column < 1:
>       TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()

Does anyone know how to do this without getting the error? I have commented in the code where the mistake is.

EDIT:

By using @stovfl's method I was able to put some of the data into the xlsx file, but as my list is a list of list, only the last list was added to my xlsx file.
I used this code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

report = load_workbook(r"C:\Myworkbook.xlsx")
ws = report.create_sheet('My sheet')
for _list in numbers:
    for row_data in _list:
        ws.append([row_data])
        print(row_data)
report.save(r"C\Myworkbook.xlsx")
```

The print:

```
A B 10
2
A B 10
3
1
AC
```

The output in the xlsx file:

[image: Output Myworkbook.xlsx]

The problem is only the last list is added, not the entire list of lists and I wanted the output to look like this:

[image: How I need it to be Myworkbook.xlsx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**:  ... only the last list was added to my xlsx file

The **First** `for loop` is your `for file in files:`.
I updated my Code below to this.

> **Question**:  how to do this without getting the error?

1. Solution writing your List of Lists using `openpyxl`, for instance

   ```
   newWorkbook = False
   newWorksheet = False

   if newWorkbook:
       from openpyxl import Workbook
       wb = Workbook()
       # Select First Worksheet
       ws = wb.worksheets[0]
   else:
       from openpyxl import load_workbook
       wb = load_workbook("mySortData.xlsx")
       if newWorksheet:
           # Create a New Worksheet in this Workbook
           ws = wb.create_chartsheet('Sheet 2')
       else:
           # Select a Worksheet by Name in this Workbook
           ws = wb['Sheet']

   for file in files:  # Getting the data from xlsx files and to the numbers-list
       df = pd.read_excel(file)
       m = (df.iloc[:, 4] - df.iloc[:, 1]) != 0
       pos = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
       numbers = (df.loc[m, df.columns[pos]].values.tolist())

       # numbers is a List[Row Data] of List[Columns]
       # Iterate List of Row Data
       for row_data in numbers:
           ws.append(row_data)

   wb.save("mySortData.xlsx")
   ```

   > **Output**:
   >   [image]
2. Solution writing your List of Lists direct to `CSV`, for instance:

   ```
   # Data == List of List
   data = [[['A B 10', 2, 'A B 10', 3, 1, 'AC'], ['A B 104', 3, 'A B 104', 2, -1, 'AC']],
   [['D B 126', 3, 'D B 126', 2, -1, 'EFG 1'], ['D B 15', 3, 'D B 15', 2, -1, 'EFG 1']],
   [],
   [],
   [['D B 544', 2, 'D B 544', 1, -1, 'EFG 11'], ['D B 152', 3, 'D B 152', 2, -1, 'EFG 11'], ['D B 682', 3, 'D B 682', 2, -1, 'EFG 11']],
   ]

   import csv
   # Write to File
   with open('Output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
       writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
       for _list in data:
           for row_data in _list:
               writer.writerow(row_data)
   ```

   > **Qutput**:
   >
   > ```
   > A B 10,2,A B 10,3,1,AC
   > A B 104,3,A B 104,2,-1,AC
   > D B 126,3,D B 126,2,-1,EFG 1
   > D B 15,3,D B 15,2,-1,EFG 1
   > D B 544,2,D B 544,1,-1,EFG 11
   > D B 152,3,D B 152,2,-1,EFG 11
   > D B 682,3,D B 682,2,-1,EFG 11
   > ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - openpyxl: 2.4.1***

Comment: With this method: Is it possible to assign which worksheet to write the data to in the output xlsx file? I need to do this.

Comment: Your Question is _**for CSV files**_, CSV don't support multiple Sheets. Using a `xlsx` Package it's possible to write to any Sheet you want.

Comment: OK, sorry, I meant in CSV form. Thanky you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is great :)

Comment: I am trying to do this in another similar example, but it is giving me TypeError.                                                                                                             Traceback: ws.append(row_data)                                                                     TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'str'>                                                                         Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I fixed the problem with ws.append([row_data]), but I am not getting the correct output so I do not know if it is right. I edited my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well but if you have a list such as :

```
l = [rows, rows, rows, ...]
```

In order to create your dataframe, you could just iterate over each element of your list l such as :

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for rows in l:
    for row in rows:
        df = pd.concat([df, row])
```

In your case, it gives me the following output :

```
    0       1   2       3   4   5
0   A B 10  2   A B 10  3   1   AC
1   A B 104 3   A B 104 2   -1  AC
0   D B 126 3   D B 126 2   -1  EFG 1
1   D B 15  3   D B 15  2   -1  EFG 1
0   D B 544 2   D B 544 1   -1  EFG 11
1   D B 152 3   D B 152 2   -1  EFG 11
2   D B 682 3   D B 682 2   -1  EFG 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can get the data into your Excel file fine. So why don't use you use something like:

`col1 = [cell.value for cell in ws['A']]`

or

`ws.iter_cols(min_col=x, max_col=y)`

If this isn't what you want then please rephrase the question to point out where the problem is.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to use this method in my case? I need the data in the list to be put in different columns in the output xlsx file. So the data needs to be split in different columns where the comma is in the example.

Comment: No, because I don't understand the description of the problem. Is the dataframe relevant to the problem?