# Adding a list to a xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, list, openpyxl

I want to add the data I have in a list to a xlsx file with python. The list looks something like this:

```
[['A B 10', 2, 'A B 10', 3, 1, AC], ['A B 104', 3, 'A B 104', 2, -1, 'AC']]
[['D B 126', 3, 'D B 126', 2, -1, 'EFG 1'], ['D B 15', 3, 'D B 15', 2, -1, 'EFG 1']
[]
[]
[['D B 544', 2, 'D B 544', 1, -1, 'EFG 11'], ['D B 152', 3, 'D B 152', 2, -1, 'EFG 11'], ['D B 682', 3, 'D B 682', 2, -1, 'EFG 11']
```

I need the data to be added to different columns suggested by the commas. So that the xlsx file will look like this:

```
     A     B    C     E   F    G
1   AB10   2   AB10   3   1    AC   
2   AB104  3   AB104  2  -1    AC
3   DB126  3   DB126  2  -1   EFG1
4   DB15   3   DB15   2  -1   EFG1
5   DB544  2   DB544  1  -1   EFG 11
etc...
```

I need to add this data to an existing excel file created with openpyxl, and I need it to be added to worksheet number 4.

I have tried a few different methods, but it is giving me errors. Have anyone got an idea on how to do this? The code I have written is inadequate and I am stuck on this issue.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

report = load_workbook(r"*.xlsx")
worksheet = report.create_sheet("Name")
for row in mainlist: #From here I am stuck (mainlist is the list with the data written above).
```

Will be happy for any ideas! I am pretty new to both python and openpyxl. Working in Python 3.4.1

Comment: Do you have a list of lists? If yes then the above list is not correctly written.

Comment: When I write print(mainlist), the list I wrote in the question is the output I get. I have gotten the data from several xlsx files earlier on, And the empty brackets in between are xlsx files I have iterated through without finding the data I wanted to add to the list.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591743/sort-data-in-a-list-to-columns-for-xlsx-files In this question I explained how I tried to sort the list before adding the list into an excel file and the error I got while doing this